# How can I sort results by aggregate in Cloudwatch Log Insights?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have a pretty straightforward query:

```
fields @timestamp, req.url, msg
| sort @timestamp desc
| filter msg = "request completed"
| stats count() by req.url
```

It presents all requests served by my app aggregated by url. However, I would also like to sort the results by the value of aggregate `count()` - but both `| sort count desc` and `| sort "count()" desc` don't work. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Turns out, all I had to do was to use an alias and then sort by it:

```
fields @timestamp, msg, req.url
| filter msg="request completed"
| stats count() as count by req.url
| sort count desc
```